# SonarQube Server trust issue with MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube, ssl-certificate, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube-ops

I want to run a SonarQube analysis of a `.NET` project.

I have set up a docker image with the prerequisites described [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Scanning+on+Linux+or+macOS).

When following the instructions:

```
mono /msbuild/SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe begin /d:sonar.login=<my-sonarqube-secret-token> /k:somenameipasshere
SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 4.0.2
Default properties file was found at /msbuild/SonarQube.Analysis.xml
Loading analysis properties from /msbuild/SonarQube.Analysis.xml
Pre-processing started.
Preparing working directories...
16:49:01.29  Updating build integration targets...
16:49:01.305  Fetching analysis configuration settings...
16:49:01.433  Failed to request and parse 'https://myserver.sonarqube.local/api/server/version': Error: TrustFailure (One or more errors occurred.)
16:49:01.433  A server certificate could not be validated. Possible cause: you are using a self-signed SSL certificate but the certificate has not been installed on the client machine. Please make sure that you can access https://myserver.sonarqube.local without encountering certificate errors.
16:49:01.434  Pre-processing failed. Exit code: 1
```

... but

```
# keytool -import -file /sonar-scanner/certs/myserver.sonarqube.local.crt -keystore /sonar-scanner/jre/lib/security/cacerts     -alias myserver.sonarqube.local -storepass <somepass> -noprompt 
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Certificate not imported, alias <myserver.sonarqube.local> already exists
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently MSBuild scanner does not operate with `keytool` as is the case with `sonar-scanner`.

One has to go through the typical (debian/ubuntu) process of copying the CA certs used by the server to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/` and run `sudo update-ca-certificates`.

Secure communication is then possible with the SonarQube server.

Comment: `mono` also needs to trust the certificate.  Depending on your distribution, you may need to add the `ca-certificates-mono` package.  http://www.mono-project.com/docs/faq/security/